# 「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と関連サイトでの対応

Tags: 討議, よくある質問, リスト質問

英語版SOや他のStack Exchangeネットワークサイトでよく物議をかもす質問の種類の 1 つに「リスト質問」(list question) または「買い物リスト質問」(shopping list question) というものがあります。

この[よくある質問](/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f)では、リスト質問がどういうものかと、英語版SOなどでの扱いを紹介します。日本語版でリスト質問をどう扱うかは、この記事を参考にしながらその都度決めていきましょう。

- どんな質問がリスト質問？
- 他のSEサイトでオフトピックな種類は？
- 「買い物リスト質問」という名前の由来
- 他のSEサイトでの一般的な扱い

  - 解決方法を聞く質問に変換する
  - 短めで客観的なリストに限定する
  - 参考文献はタグWikiに入れる
  - クローズする
  - チャットで聞く

---

他のSEサイトでの扱いについての参考資料（英語）:

- [なぜリスト質問はよくないのか](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185486/157841)
- [リスト質問の定義](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124489/157841)
- [おすすめ質問の定義](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254394/20226)
- [リスト質問はコミュニティWikiにすればいいのでは?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/157841)
- [ux.SEではオフトピック](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/783/3924)
- [music.SEではオフトピック](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/162)

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 16):

### どんな質問がリスト質問？

リスト質問というのは例えば:

- おすすめのRuby入門書を教えてください
- 404ページのデザイン例を教えてください
- Flaskを採用している国内の有名サイトは？
- Android初心者が取り組むべきチュートリアルを教えてください

など、色々な回答が沢山出てくるような質問です。

ここでは

- 解決すべき問題がなく、興味本位で聞いているリスト質問
- 何を含めるかが主観的なリスト質問
- 参考文献の一覧を聞いているリスト質問

と「それ以外の広い意味でのリスト質問（回答が単に一覧形式になる質問）」を分けて考えます<sup>1</sup>。

### 他のSEサイトでオフトピックな種類は？

上にあげた 3 つの種類の質問、興味本位・主観的・参考文献についてのリスト質問は、ヘルプの「[どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)」ページでいう、

- どの回答も同様に有効
- 質問と一緒に回答も提示され、さらに他の回答を期待している: 私は X に Y を使っています。皆さんは何を使っていますか?
- 解決すべき実際の問題がない

があてはまることが多く、Stack Exchangeサイトで想定しているQ&A形式に沿っていないため、英語版SOを含めオフトピック扱いとなっているサイトが多いです。

なぜかというと、

- 内容がすぐに古くなりがち (リンク切れ含む)  
  → サイトの価値が薄れてしまう
- 自己宣伝（またはステマ) やリンクだけの回答が多くなりがち  
  → ノイズが増えてサイトの価値が薄れる
- 具体的な問題ではなく、正解というものがないので、投票もしにくく、ベストアンサーも選びにくい  
  → あいまいな状態のQ&Aや単なる人気投票になりがちで、Stack Overflowで期待されるコンテンツではない
- 回答が主観的な内容になりがちで、何を含めるかもあいまい  
  → エキスパートによる回答が集まるはずのサイトとしての価値が薄れてしまう

「内容がすぐ古くなりがち」なのは、みんなでメンテすればいいじゃん、と思われるかもしれませんが、Stack Overflow上になくてもいいわけです。
[無料のプログラミング本の一覧](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#professional-development)のようにGitHub上でメンテするという選択肢もあります。これは元々は[Stack Overflow上の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/20226)だったものです<sup>2</sup>。また、「みんな」に責任を分散すると、結局誰もやらないという経験則もあります。

Stack Overflowのミッションは、プログラミングに関連する質問に回答を提供して、日々問題解決をしている世の中のプログラマーの役に立つことです。「Xの一覧は何？」が質問として役に立たないというわけではありません。が、「どうすればYできる？」という形式の質問に合わせてStack Overflowが作られているのが実情で、「Xの一覧は何？」というリスト質問はStack Overflowには合わない、というのが英語版での結論です。

### 「買い物リスト質問」という名前の由来

コンピューター関係のエンドユーザー向けのQ&Aサイト、[Super User](http://superuser.com)が4年程前に始まりました。そこで問題になったのが「どの製品を買えばいいか、おすすめを教えてください」というタイプの質問です。

これは回答が主観的になりがちで、また状況と時期が限定されすぎているので、多くの人の役に立たない、という理由から[オフトピックと認定されました](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1103/should-we-add-a-no-shopping-recommendation-clause-to-the-super-user-faq)。その後[Stack Overflow公式ブログでも紹介され](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)、Stack Exchange全体でも問題になりやすい質問タイプとして認識されるようになっていきました。

「何を買えばいいか、おすすめを教えてください」のような買い物質問を、「Xを教えてください」という方向で改善しようとすると、リスト質問にいきつきます<sup>3</sup>。例えば:

> #### 現時点で一番コスパのよいXを教えてください
>
> 型名と、ショップへのリンクもお願いします。先週の同様の質問ではおそらくもう情報が古くなっているので、現時点での情報が知りたいです。

価格は変動が激しいので、他の人の役に立つ質問ではすぐになくなってしまいます。価格情報は省くことにすると、今度は「おすすめを聞く質問」に様変わりします:

> #### 一番よいXを教えてください
>
> 今出回っている製品はどれもよさげに見えます。どれが一番よい製品ですか?

これは回答が主観的になりすぎるので、

> #### Xの一覧を教えてください
>
> どう製品があるか知りたいので一覧がほしいです。

とすると、興味本位のリスト質問になります。これでは回答がメンテ不可能な長さになります。そこで何の問題に直面しているかを具体的に書くようにすると:

> #### ○○を××できるようなXを教えてください
>
> 今は某Yを使っているのですが、途中でオーバーヒートして止まってしまいます。

これは広い意味でリスト質問の一種ですが、解決すべき問題がはっきり述べられているので、興味本位ではないというのが分かります。「Xを教えてください」ではない方向で言い換える例が、次にあります。

### 他のSEサイトでの一般的な扱い

「おすすめは?」「一覧が知りたい」と聞くのが即アウトなわけではなく、「具体的な問題が根底にあるか」をまず確かめます。

#### 解決方法を聞く質問に変換する

具体的な問題があれば、「Xの一覧は何？」から「どうすればYできる？」というように、具体的で解決可能な質問に言いかえることができます。そうすれば、Stack Overflowが想定している形式にうまく収まるかたちで質問・回答できます。

上の「買い物質問の由来」の最後の例で言うと、例えば

> #### オーバーヒートさせずに○○を××するにはどうすればいいですか?
>
> 今はYを使ってやろうとしているのですが、うまくいきません。

という言い換えになります。言葉のあやではないか、と思われるかもしれませんが、「どうすればいいか」を聞くことで、延々と続く製品一覧ではなくて、解決方法を回答できるような質問になります。

[「なぜなぜ分析」](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9C%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90)を使って、「なぜ」を5回繰り返してみると、何が問題かはっきりするかもしれません。

1. 解決したい問題を説明する
2. これまでにやってみたことを説明する
3. どうなってほしいかを説明して、助けを求める

この手順を踏むことで、回答がぞくぞくとやってきてベストアンサーを選ぶのに困る、という事態を避けることができます。

#### 短めで客観的なリストに限定する

うまくStack Exchangeプラットフォームで扱えるタイプの「リスト質問」もあります。

- リストに含まれるものの個数が限定されていて、長くなりすぎない
- リストに載せるものの条件が具体的・客観的に定義されている
- リストの内容が時間が経ってもそうそう変わらない
- きちんと網羅した回答がある・提供できる

という条件を満たす質問なら、十分具体性があって、他のStack Exchangeサイトでも受け入れられている場合が多いです<sup>4</sup>。

例えば [他のオブジェクト指向言語に経験のあるプログラマがRubyを覚えるための簡潔な日本語の説明](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/423/30) はこれにあてはまります。

他のSEサイトの例でいうと、dsp.SEでは「具体的であること」という条件付きで、[おすすめ本を聞く質問をOKとしています](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68/asking-for-book-suggestions-on-topic)。単に「おすすめは?」ではなく、「経験的モード分解をEEGシグナルに適用する場合を解説した論文や本はありませんか?」という具合です。

条件が具体的になってくると、明示的に「これにあてはまるものはありますか?」と聞くかどうかの違いであって、上の解決方法を聞く質問との差はそんなに無いとも言えます。

#### 参考文献はタグWikiに入れる

英語版の[php](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)タグなどは、タグWiki内にチュートリアルなどの参考資料のリンクをまとめています。

#### クローズする

ここまでにあてはまらない質問がメインサイトにあれば、クローズに投票します。5票集まれば自動的にクローズされます。

#### チャットで聞く

[チャット](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)では、そのサイト・部屋に関連したことであれば大体何でも聞いて大丈夫です。

---

<sup>1</sup>この分類は、この記事独自のものです。  
<sup>2</sup>英語版SOでは歴史的経緯から残されているリスト質問もありますが、現在はクローズされているか、ロックされています。  
<sup>3</sup>この部分は、[なぜリスト質問はよくないのか](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185486/157841)から抜粋しました。  
<sup>4</sup>Stack Exchangeメタ: [よいリスト質問とよくないリスト質問がある? への回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180369/157841)より