# 「Unity初心者がとりくむべきチュートリアル」はタグWikiに入れた方がよい？

Tags: 討議, リスト質問

「[Xの一覧が知りたいという質問の傾向](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/30)」（長文注意）は、この質問のための前準備です =)

[「Unity初心者がとりくむべきチュートリアル」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1531/30) は英語版SOではメインサイトで扱わないようにしている種類の質問にあてはまると思います。主に問題になると思う点は:

- どのチュートリアルを回答として含めるかの基準があいまい（主観的）  
  → 資料集としてのクオリティが劣化しがち

こうした質問に関して英語版のコミュニティがこれまでに得た知見を参考に、より役立つまとめ方を模索したいです。例えば、英語版にならって、[unity3d](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)の[タグWiki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/info)でチュートリアルをまとめるという選択肢もあります。

タグWikiは、そのタグに関連した情報をコミュニティ内で自由に管理できるスペースです。英語版の [php](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) タグや  [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) タグなどは、ここに参考文献やサイト内で参考になる質問をまとめたりしています。メリットとして:

- チュートリアルのまとめがどこかの質問に埋もれているよりも、辿りつきやすい。
- タグWikiを直に編集するには信用度が1500以上必要で、何を入れて何を入れないかの判断基準を編集者がしっかり持っていることを期待できる。

  - 通常の投稿を直に編集するには1000以上の信用度が必要。これはベータ中の数値で、卒業するとそれぞれ5000と2000になる。

みなさんはどう考えますか？タグWikiに移動した方がよいですか？日本語版ではメインサイトで参考文献をメンテしてみますか？その場合、英語版のコミュニティがこれまでに経験してきたネガティブな側面についてはどのように考えますか？

---

更新: scala タグへのリンクを追加、投稿者の意見をもう少し前面に出しました。

Comment: 質問する前に見ましょう的な情報をタグWikiに書くというのは悪くない案ですね。特に公式のリソースやデファクトになっているドキュメント、書籍など一定のコンテキストを置くにはふさわしい気がします。

Comment: @YusukeAndo 英語のSOでは、一部のタグはそれを実施しています。[例：scala](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info)

Comment: 厳選した本当に価値のあるチュートリアル･書籍だけをピックアップしたリストは非常に役に立つのですが作るとなるとなかなか難しいですね。

Answer (score 6):

英語版のSOに同じ悩みがありました。[ブログでこれについて記事を書きました](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)（英語のみ）。fliedonionが[和訳してくれた](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%BA%96%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E3%81%AB-qa-is-hard-let-s-go-shopping-%E3%82%92%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F?lq=1)ので、参考になると思います：

> ## Q&A って大変だな、買い物にでも出かけよう！
>
> 11-23-10 by Jeff Atwood.
>
> この二年半の間、私たちのサイト（Stackoverflow）で尋ねられる傾向のある、問題ある種類の質問を明らかにした。
>   これらの多くはわれわれの[打ち切る理由としての標準セット](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/)（完全に既出、オフトピック、主観や論争、質問でない、局地的すぎる、）
>   に文書化されます。
>
> しかしながら、我々がローンチした[Super
>
>   Userでの偉大な経験](https://superuser.com/)により、今まで出てこなかった種類の問題ある質問がでてきました-**お買い物の質問です**。
>
> [ブログ画像 http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/barbie-shopping.jpg](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/barbie-shopping.jpg)
>
> つまりですね、Super Userで私たちはこんな質問に出会いました:
>
> ```
> Macbook Air と Macbook Pro どっちがいい？  
> 最高のデュアルバンドワイアレスルータは？  
> Dell GX280 のプロセッサはいいやつに変わった？  
> どのRAMを買うべき？  
> ビデオカードは nVidia？ATI？
> ```
>
> これらの質問は、一見許容しても良いように見えるかもしれません。 我々の仲間イウォークユーザーを助けるのは、我々の任務ではありませんか？
>   しかし、きちんと買い物の質問に答えるためにはあなたは相当量の情報が必要だと考えてください。
>
> - 予算は？
> - どこに住んでいるの？
> - あなたの好みは？
> - 選択肢として受け入れられるのは？
> - いつ買うつもり？
>
> じゃぁ質問者がこれらの情報をすべて提供したとしましょう。そんなのありえないと私もわかっているけど、
>   それには嘘をついて、完全、理想的なおすすめの買い物を提供したとします。 たとえそれがホントだったとしても、
>   **最高の買い物も1年以内に時代遅れとなるほどテクノロジーの進化は速い** のです！ 限られた（局地的とも言われるかも）閲覧者へ一時的な利益だけを提供する質問ばかりの労働集約型質問掲示板に 何か意味があるのでしょうか？
>   何もありません。 これが私たちの結論です。そして我々は [Super User
>
>   FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)で買い物の質問を[はっきりと許可しません](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1103/should-we-add-a-no-shopping-recommendation-clause-to-the-super-user-faq)でした:
>
> ```
> Super Userはコンピュータファンとパワーユーザーのためのサイトです。もし以下に関する質問をお持ちなら
>
> * コンピューターハードウェア
> * コンピューターソフトウェア
>
> そしてそれが以下に **当てはまらない** なら
>
> * ビデオゲームやゲーム機
> * Facebook, Twitter, WordPressといったウェブサイトやウェブサービス
> * 電子デバイス、音楽・動画などのプレイヤー、携帯電話やスマートホン（あなたのコンピューターと接続する場合を除いて）
> * `買い物関連、お買い得情報`
> ```
>
> **しかしながら**、お買い物質問固有の問題を回避しつつ、これらの質問をする方法があります。 たとえば、あなたには欲しいものがあります -さっき私がやったように- あなたは暗い場所でも綺麗に取れるカメラが 買いたいのです。なので、当然のごとく [photo.stackexchange.com](http://photo.stackexchange.com) で質問するわけです。
>
> 一つ質問の例を挙げてみます:
>
> ```
> ** Q: オートフォーカスのカメラでベストなのはどれですか？**
>
> A: Canon S90 と Lumix LX3です。
> ```
>
> もう一つ質問の例を挙げてみましょう:
>
> ```
> Q: オートフォーカスのカメラが、微光でも綺麗に取れるかどうかはどこでわかりますか？
>
> A: 私が特におさえておいた方がいいと思うポイントは
>
> * 高速レンズ (少なくとも2.0)
> * ほどよいISO感度 （すくなくとも 400、なるべくなら 800がいい）
> * センサーサイズが最大の物
> これら全ての要素が微光環境での撮影には本当に大事です
> ```
>
> 前者の質問は一番楽な道です:
>   私があまりかんがえずに買える長い製品のリストになります。ですがその種の回答はせいぜい1年ぐらい有効なだけです。後者の質問はいくらか考える必要があるかもしれません、しかしその回答はずっと使える...それか少なくともカメラの技術が今日知られるようなレンズとセンサーの範囲を超えたところにシフトするまでは有効です。
>   かくして、買い物についての質問であれば何を買えばいいかを尋ねるのはやめましょう －
>   あなたがどれを買うべきか見分けるために何を学ばねばならないのかを尋ねてください。
>
> 我々のネットワークを一つの言葉にまとめなければならないならば、それは「**学習**」です。
>   人々は彼らが熱心なテーマについて学ぶために私たちのサイトを訪れるのです。古い中国のことわざにこんなものがあります
>   「魚を一匹やれば１日食いつなぐが、魚の取り方を教えてやれば一生食いはぐれることはない」
>   全ての質問と回答は最終的に教育と学習として利用できなければなりません－そう、買い物の事でさえもね。