# 質問の基準の参考に「Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping! 」を翻訳してみました

Tags: サポート, 質問の仕方, リスト質問, stackoverflow.blog

stackoverflowネットワークの質問に対する方針が垣間見えるこちらのブログを翻訳してみました。

これに従おうという事 **ではなく** 日本語コミュニティでどうするかの判断材料の一つとして使えればいいと思います。
訳のひどい部分もあると思いますので、編集などもどしどしお願いします。

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

---

## Q&A って大変だな、買い物にでも出かけよう！

11-23-10 by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/jeffatwood/).

この二年半の間、私たちのサイト（Stackoverflow）で尋ねられる傾向のある、問題ある種類の質問を明らかにした。
これらの多くはわれわれの[打ち切る理由としての標準セット](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/)（完全に既出、オフトピック、主観や論争、質問でない、局地的すぎる、）
に文書化されます。

しかしながら、我々がローンチした[Super Userでの偉大な経験](https://superuser.com/)により、今まで出てこなかった種類の問題ある質問がでてきました-**お買い物の質問です**。

[image: ブログ画像]

つまりですね、Super Userで私たちはこんな質問に出会いました:

```
Macbook Air と Macbook Pro どっちがいい？  
最高のデュアルバンドワイアレスルータは？  
Dell GX280 のプロセッサはいいやつに変わった？  
どのRAMを買うべき？  
ビデオカードは nVidia？ATI？
```

これらの質問は、一見許容しても良いように見えるかもしれません。
我々の仲間イウォークユーザーを助けるのは、我々の任務ではありませんか？
しかし、きちんと買い物の質問に答えるためにはあなたは相当量の情報が必要だと考えてください。

- 予算は？
- どこに住んでいるの？
- あなたの好みは？
- 選択肢として受け入れられるのは？
- いつ買うつもり？

じゃぁ質問者がこれらの情報をすべて提供したとしましょう。そんなのありえないと私もわかっているけど、
それには嘘をついて、完全、理想的なおすすめの買い物を提供したとします。
たとえそれがホントだったとしても、 **最高の買い物も1年以内に時代遅れとなるほどテクノロジーの進化は速い** のです！
限られた（局地的とも言われるかも）閲覧者へ一時的な利益だけを提供する質問ばかりの労働集約型質問掲示板に
何か意味があるのでしょうか？
何もありません。
これが私たちの結論です。そして我々は [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)で買い物の質問を[はっきりと許可しません](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1103/should-we-add-a-no-shopping-recommendation-clause-to-the-super-user-faq)でした:

```
Super Userはコンピュータファンとパワーユーザーのためのサイトです。もし以下に関する質問をお持ちなら

* コンピューターハードウェア
* コンピューターソフトウェア

そしてそれが以下に **当てはまらない** なら

* ビデオゲームやゲーム機
* Facebook, Twitter, WordPressといったウェブサイトやウェブサービス
* 電子デバイス、音楽・動画などのプレイヤー、携帯電話やスマートホン（あなたのコンピューターと接続する場合を除いて）
* `買い物関連、お買い得情報`
```

**しかしながら**、お買い物質問固有の問題を回避しつつ、これらの質問をする方法があります。
たとえば、あなたには欲しいものがあります -さっき私がやったように- あなたは暗い場所でも綺麗に取れるカメラが
買いたいのです。なので、当然のごとく [photo.stackexchange.com](http://photo.stackexchange.com) で質問するわけです。

一つ質問の例を挙げてみます:

```
Q: オートフォーカスのカメラでベストなのはどれですか？

A: Canon S90 と Lumix LX3です。
```

もう一つ質問の例を挙げてみましょう:

```
Q: オートフォーカスのカメラが、微光でも綺麗に取れるかどうかはどこでわかりますか？

A: 私が特におさえておいた方がいいと思うポイントは

* 明るいレンズ (少なくとも2.0)
* ほどよいISO感度 （すくなくとも 400、なるべくなら 800がいい）
* センサーサイズが最大の物
これら全ての要素が微光環境での撮影には本当に大事です
```

前者の質問は楽ちんです: （回答によって）あまり何も考えずに買い物に出かけられるおつかいメモが出来上がります。ですがその種の回答はせいぜい1年ぐらい有効なだけです。後者の質問はいくらか考える必要があるかもしれません、しかしその回答はずっと使える...それか少なくともカメラの技術が今日知られるようなレンズとセンサーの範囲を超えたところにシフトするまでは有効です。
かくして、買い物についての質問であれば何を買えばいいかを尋ねるのはやめましょう － あなたがどれを買うべきか見分けるために何を学ばねばならないのかを尋ねてください。

我々のネットワークを一つの言葉にまとめなければならないならば、それは「**学習**」です。
人々は彼らが熱心なテーマについて学ぶために私たちのサイトを訪れるのです。古い中国のことわざにこんなものがあります
「魚を一匹やれば１日食いつなぐが、魚の取り方を教えてやれば一生食いはぐれることはない」
全ての質問と回答は最終的に教育と学習として利用できなければなりません－そう、買い物の事でさえもね。

Comment: 関連討議：http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1384/unity%e5%88%9d%e5%bf%83%e8%80%85%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a8%e3%82%8a%e3%81%8f%e3%82%80%e3%81%b9%e3%81%8d%e3%83%81%e3%83%a5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e3%83%aa%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab-%e3%81%af%e3%82%bf%e3%82%b0wiki%e3%81%ab%e5%85%a5%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9f%e6%96%b9%e3%81%8c%e3%82%88%e3%81%84?rq=1