# この質問がモデレーター権限でクローズされた理由は何ですか？

Tags: サポート, モデレーション

この質問、[『YouTubeのようなサイト（またはアプリ）を開発する場合、サーバ側の要求スペックの考え方を教えてください。』](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/89445/3054)はモデレーター権限でクローズされています。

- モデレーター権限による即時的なクローズが必要だった理由は何ですか？
- どのような編集が行なわれれば再オープンされますか？

Comment: この質問の前提として、モデレーターを担当している(または任命された)ユーザーは、個々の事例でモデレーター権限での操作と一般ユーザーとしての操作を使い分けることが可能なのか？ というのは、どこかで明らかになっているのでしょうか？ ヘルプ記事だと使い分けが出来る/出来ないとも明確にはなっていないような気がしますが。

Comment: @kunif さん> [モデレーションの理論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/32986)によれば、モデレーターがクローズ票や削除票を投票すると、その時点でそれらのアクションが実行される（クローズや削除が確定する）ようです。

Comment: @kunif StackOverflow でのモデレーターは、クローズ投票などの一般のモデレーションを行えません。
モデレーターによるモデレーションは強制力があり即時執行となります。
ただし、投票をしたいモデレーターはワークアラウンドとして、「最後の一票」を投じることがあります。
例えばクローズに必要なのは5票なので、クローズに4票入った時点でモデレーターがクローズすると、5人目に一般の権限で投票したかのような結果となります。

Comment: そういうモデレーター1人だけによる処理をされている記事は普通に一杯ある(見かけている)と思うのですが、この記事だけモデレーター権限の行使を重大(過大?)と見做すのは何故かを追記した方が意見も出やすいと思われます。

Comment: @kunif 一応確認ですが、私は意見を求めていないです。モデレーター権限が使われた理由を質問しているだけです。もちろん、意見をお寄せいただく分には歓迎ですし、読ませていただきますが。

Comment: @kunif 「モデレーター1人だけによる処理をされている記事は普通に一杯ある」というのは私の観測とは異ります。 [サイト モデレーターとは誰で、ここでの役割は何ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)に書かれている「まれな例外的状況」でのみ、モデレーターの方は動いていると思います。英語による質問だけは実態として「まれ」ではないですが、本来は例外的であるはずのものだと思います。

Comment: @mjy さん、まあ確かに英語だけの質問とか明らかにおかしな投稿とか十分に根拠のあるもののような印象だったので、一杯あるはいい加減な言葉でしたね。すみません。ちなみにモデレーターツール(信用度2000以上)やアクセス解析(信用度5000以上)とかで信用度のある人ならクローズ投票した人数とか見られませんかね。今サイトのリストから質問をたどっていくと最近のいくつか以外はクローズされた記事は表示されなくなっていました。既に本人またはシステムによって削除されているのかもしれません。

Comment: @kunif 「クローズ投票した人数とか見られませんかね」-> 少しトリッキーですが、
https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1610025/close-history-in-order-of-number-of-voters
で見れると思います。たぶん、削除されたものは含まれていなくて、再オープンされたものは含まれています。

Comment: @kunif さん、私の知る限り、モデレーターが一般ユーザーとして何かしらの操作を行うことはできません。クローズ票の投票もそのひとつで、モデレーターが行った場合は必ず一発クローズになります。

Answer (score 2):

コメントでたずねて @mjy さん自身に見つけてもらった結果では、モデレーター権限で1人でクローズして、まだ残っている記事はそこそこあるようです。
昨年と今年は増えているようですね。
私の印象も少しは状況に合っていたのだと安堵しています。

```
年  :1人でクローズ/全 件数
--------------------------
2022: 12 / 19
2021: 23 / 39
2020:  5 / 31
2019:  7 / 27
2018:  5 / 56
2017:  0 / 53
2016:  2 / 42
2015:  5 / 60
2014:  5 /  7
--------------------------
全    64 /334  19.16%
```

そういうデータを背景に傍から見ていると、そんなに強い調子で言う必要があるほどの「特異なモデレーション」とは思えないのですが。
あるいはたまたま今回気付いてこだわったということでしょうか。

元記事の質問者さんは、自身の質問とコメントの応酬において以下3点を意識していると考えられます。

- マナー的お約束的な謙遜かもしれませんが、自身の質問が曖昧で大まかで具体性に欠ける内容であること。
- コメントで助言やキーワードにより今後の調査の方向性を示してもらったため、それで解決した(あるいは十分)と考えている。
- そのため質問がクローズされても自分自身は特に問題は無い。

元記事の質問者さんは、既に質問内容やあるかもしれない回答に対する興味が薄れて、自身の今後の調査をどうするかに移ってきて、質問を再開するとか誰が何故クローズしたかにはこだわっていないのでは？ という気がします。

---

意見を出すなら立ち位置や姿勢が重要ということでお勧めに従って、私の考えは：

例外的では無くても妥当な理由ならモデレーターはモデレーター権限でクローズしてよい

というものです。
それで、元記事の扱いは妥当で問題無いと考えています。

Comment: 確認ですが、結局の所 kunif さんはこの件に関して、モデレーター権限による即時的なクローズが必要だったとお考えですか？ だとすると、その理由は何ですか？
もしくは、過去にはモデレーター権限による即時的なクローズが不必要に行なわれて来た、と考えられていて、その事から今回も理由を尋ねても仕方ない、という何か諦めのようなご意見なのでしょうか。
（私は過去のモデレーションに問題が有ったとは思いません。数件、疑義を呈した事はありますが、全て対応いただいています）

Comment: 私自身は何も問題とは考えていません。他にそうした事例があったとしても気付いていませんでした。逆に何故 @mjy さんがそんなにこだわるのかのほうが不思議に感じてコメントやこの投稿をしています。

Comment: 「何も問題とは考えていません」というのは、「今回はモデレーター権限によるクローズが必要な例外的理由があった」ということですか？ その場合は、その理由を説明して下さい。
私がこのメタ質問で求めているのは、ただそれだけです。
それとも「例外的な理由が無くとも、モデレーターはモデレーター権限でクローズしてよい」とお考えですか？
その場合、私とは意見が異なりますが、おっしゃることは理解します。

Comment: ほんの少し違って、「例外的では無くても妥当な理由ならモデレーターはモデレーター権限でクローズしてよい」と考えています。

Comment: 「例外的では無くても妥当な理由なら〜」なるほど、この表現でしたら明快でよく理解できました。
この回答に反映していただけると解り易いかと思います。

Comment: なお、モデレーター権限が行使された件数をもって、今回のモデレーションが特異でない、とご主張のようにも取れますが、それは奇妙な論理だと思います。
件数でなく内容を見なければ、意味がないはずです。
私の観測では、モデレーターチームの方々は、cubickさんも含め、「例外処理機」として働いて下さっています。
モデレーター権限でクローズされてきたのは、英語の質問、コピペのような（本当にコピペのこともあります）重複質問、何の手掛りもなく何か貼り付けるのを忘れたかのような質問、などなどです。
何かしらの議論の余地があるような理由で、クローズするようなモデレーションは行われていません。
履歴を一つ一つ確認いただければお解りいただけると思います。

Comment: その辺は @mjy さんがモデレーター権限によるクローズに特にこだわっている理由が分からないので、そういう手続きの流れ(一般ユーザーの指摘が最低一人は必要？)に従っているかどうかにこだわったのかと推測して、流れに従っていない例も多くあるのでは？として出しています。さかのぼって整合性を保ちながら書き変えるのは面倒なので、途中経過としてご容赦願います。

Answer (score 0):

クローズとして判断した経緯は以下の通りです。

質問では「どのようなスペックのサーバが望まれるでしょうか」と書かれていますが、提示されている情報では具体的な規模感もまだ定まっていない様子であり、コメント欄でも私自身を含めていくつか指摘のある通り一概に答えを出すのは難しいと思ったこと、指摘コメントに対してもある程度のプラス票も入っていたためクローズと判断しました。
いわゆる "買い物 (リスト) 質問" に近い状態なのかなと思いました。

**参考:**

- [「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と関連サイトでの対応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381)
- [質問の基準の参考に「Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping! 」を翻訳してみました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1432)

質問の本文を見る限りでは具体的なスペックを求めているものと読めたのでクローズと判断しましたが、例えば「スペックを選定するためには何を考慮すればいいか」のような質問であれば主観的な答えにはならずに回答も付けやすいと思いました。

Comment: cubick さんが主観性が高いと考えた理由は分かりました。
しかし、私がこのメタ質問で知りたいのは、モデーレーター権限を使った理由です。