# 適切な質問かの討議：面白イースターエッグ

Tags: 討議, クローズ理由

[面白イースターエッグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1671/%E9%9D%A2%E7%99%BD%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A8%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0)の質問は、質問の範囲が広すぎるので、スタックオーバーフローには適切ではないとも考えられますが、皆さんの意見をお聞かせください。
例えば、このようなタイプの質問も面白いので、問題無いというようなご意見が多ければ、そのまま残しておこうと思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

英語版開設当初の Stackoverflow ならこういうのも許されたかもしれないですが、最近のルールに則ったカルチャーでの Stackoverflow だと考えると、「面白いイースターエッグ」はいわゆる get-to-know-you とか [「Xの一覧が知りたい」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381/x%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7%E3%81%8C%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%82%BE%E5%90%91%E3%81%A8%E4%BB%96%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C)、what's your favorite X? と言われる類の質問なので、アウトでしょう。

ただ、日本語版の開設にあたって、いきなりルールギチギチで運営していくのか、多少アウトローでもユーザを増やして盛り上げていくのかはアドミン陣の手腕が問われるところかもしれません。
すごく盛り上がったのに、後で消されて腹がたった [New programming jargon you coined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined) の件とかもあるので、後で消すぐらいなら最初っからルール統一した方がいいかもですが。

Comment: 消さずとも、モデレートされていれば検索スコアも低くなって大丈夫という気もするのですがどうでしょうか。
消すよりも、良いものを目立たせる方向で対処できればいいなぁと思っています。

ただ、ハラスメント的なものとか即刻削除するものは決めておいてもいいかもしれません。

Comment: @YusukeAndo / Eugene コメントを基づいて、とりあえず質問をクローズしました。このままで消さないので、コミュニティが例の一部として残ります。