# この質問は条件が曖昧で、一旦クローズすべきではないでしょうか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

これまでにも [アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0) タグで様々な「より良い実装は？」質問が投稿されていますが・・・。

[数値からランダムに値を取り出す『軽い』方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/23948/8000)

> 0から19までの連続した値があるとし、そこから重複せずに六つだけ取り出したいと思います。
>
> (中略)
>
> 1.コレクションなどの機能は使用しない
>   2.forやifなどといった、基本的な処理だけで実現したい
>   3.取得した後も、昇順に並んでいること
>   4.簡単なことだけに、極力コードを少なくしたい

「コレクションなどの機能」「基本的な処理」の範囲が曖昧ですし、「極力コードを少なくしたい」の程度もはっきりしません。これらの条件は言語にも依存するように思いますが、言語の指定はありません。回答しにくいのもそうですが、評価基準がはっきりしないので投票もしにくいと感じます。

また、一つでも回答がついていればそこに別解を出すハードルは下がるように思います。そんな実装にするぐらいならこっちの方がいいのに、参考までにこういうのもありますね、等々。既に5件回答がついていますが、質問の条件を満たしているのかは謎です。

そういった状態のままこの質問や回答を受け入れる流れを作らないためにも、要件がもう少しはっきりするまで一旦クローズしてもいいのでは？と思ったのですが、別にそうでもないのでしょうか。

<sub>もっとも、下手に条件を絞り込まれるよりも漠然と「好きな言語で好きなアルゴリズムで実装してください」という形式の方が、Q&Aとしての汎用性は高いかもしれないなと思ったり。Qに合わないという点に関しては、Aに合うようにQを変えてしまうことも可能ですし。</sub>

### 関連

- [適切な質問かの討議：面白イースターエッグ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1417/8000)
- ["OSが作れない言語はありますか" がオフトピックの理由](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2056/8000)

Comment: 件の質問は明らかにコードゴルフではありません。「コードゴルフのような」質問に関して議論するのであれば、例として不適切なので外したほうがよいと思います。件の質問についての議論が必要ならば「コードゴルフ」云々の方を修正していただけますか。何についての問題提起かいまいち分からないです。

Comment: @mjy なんとなく、（コード長に限らず）競い合うようなものを想像していたのですが、それはコードゴルフではないですね。大変失礼いたしました。

Answer (score 9):

#### 曖昧な質問一般に関して

問題の種類にもよりますが、基本的には厳密な仕様を書けるのは実装も出来る人です。
質問サイトである以上、また数学ならざるプログラミングの話である以上、ある程度の曖昧さは必然です。
程度問題ということになるかと思います。

曖昧な質問は「一旦クローズ」してブラッシュアップした後、すぐに再オープンできれば理想だと思います。
しかし、とても曖昧な質問はいくらでもありますし、ヒューマンリソース的に現状このサイトでは無理だと感じます。
「自分は読解出来た。回答出来る。」と思った人にまかせて見て、様子を見てもよいのではないでしょうか。
最後に編集して形を整える事も出来ますし。
「よく読めば、だいたい想像付く」程度の曖昧さなら許容して欲しいです。

#### 件の質問に関して

私は特段曖昧な質問だとは思いません。
突っ込みが多いという事は厳密さを期待出来そうで、そうでない微妙なラインだったのかも知れません。
私の理解は以下です。

> 「コレクションなどの機能」「基本的な処理」の範囲が曖昧ですし

言語や環境に用意されている機能を呼び出して一丁上り、をやりたい分けではない事が分かります。
厳密に定義するような物ではありません。

> 「極力コードを少なくしたい」の程度もはっきりしません

「初歩的な質問」といっているのですから、競技者レベルとかではなく「すっきり書きたい」程度の話だと分かります。

> 配列のシャッフルは結構高レベルの操作なので、「コレクションなどの機能は使用しない」と矛盾します

だから「どうもうまくないな」と思って質問しているのです。

> あと、「0～19の連続した値」という条件は絶対なのでしょうか

「あるとし、」ですから、例えばという事で、絶対とかそういう話ではありません。
巨大数的な何かと戦っているわけではない、という程度の意味合いはあるでしょう。

> アルゴリズムが聞きたいのか、具体的にこの問題インスタンスがときたいのか

「この問題インスタンスがときたい」ならばライブラリの機能でも探すでしょう。自明です。

> 同じ内容の回答がさまざまなプログラム言語で以って書かれていて冗長になっています

かぶっているのはCとPythonがありますね。自分が読み易い方を読めばよいと思います。便利です。

Answer (score 6):

クローズ票については、自分では積極的に投票しませんがレビューで回ってきたら承認してたと思います。コメントで指摘したように質問の前提が明確でないので明確にして欲しいと思いました。

「私はこう解釈して回答した」の「回答した」の部分を否定するわけではありません。[mjyさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/23957/5793)は素晴らしい内容だと思います。不十分な質問に良い回答をしろ的なことはヘルプセンターのどこかにも書いてあったような気がしまし、それに対するバッジもあるぐらいです。

今回の質問については、素晴らしい回答が付き、趣旨についても後追いで補足されたので、結果オーライだと思います。ただ今回がレアケースで、いつもそうとは限りません。

SOの理想としては、疑問の余地がない質問がありそれに対して疑問の余地がない回答が集約されることで「趣旨不明瞭な疑問と雑多な回答の雑多な集合」ではない有用なQ&Aリソースを目指しているのだと考えています。なので、回答することと改善の提案(疑問点の呈示)をすることは対立するわけではなく、両立するものだと思います。

コメントでの指摘やクローズ票は「曖昧であるからけしからん」という意思表示ではありません。曖昧な点が改善されるのであれば、質問者にとっても回答しようとしている人にとっても後から同じ疑問に当たった第三者にも良いことのはずです。

にもかかわらず、改善の指摘やクローズ票が否定的にとらえられている、場合によっては個人攻撃だととらえられている事については検討が必要かも知れませんね。

Answer (score 5):

質問者さんは、自分なりに考えてみたところ「コレクションやソートを使った方法は思いついたけど、それらを使わずにやる良い方法はないだろうか？」という意図で質問されたものと解釈しました。

配列を使わずソートもしないで昇順に並んでいること、と言う条件は、結構良い点をついているのではないでしょうか？

普通に思いつく方法だと簡単にできるけど、もっと画期的な方法はないか、というのは、私は「良い質問」だと思うので、クローズには反対します。

Comment: 「配列を使わずソートもしないで昇順に並んでいること、と言う条件」は明記されていないと思います。条件が曖昧なので人によってこのように「解釈」が変わるのでよくないよね、という話です。

Comment: コレクションはコンテナと言うべきかもしれませんが、その点が曖昧だとしても、文脈からバッファメモリ／ストレージの類は使いたくないというのは読み取れます。ソートはストレージが存在することが前提なので、ストレージがないならソートもなしというのは明らかです。「昇順に並んでいること」というのは質問文に書かれています。質問文には「一度シャッフルして再びソートするというのが無駄に思えてなりません」とあるので、これを回避する方法はないでしょうか、と意図しているのは読解できます。

Answer (score 1):

この問題に限っての話ですが、質問者の書き出しと文脈を読むと、計算量的な話がしたかったのかなと理解して、それを表現するとコレクション云々の話になったのかなと思いました。想像ですが。

「極力コードを短くしたい」だと確かにゴルフ的ですが、たとえば計算量に最適化したアルゴリズムはもはや読めない、という場合もありますので、「なるべくシンプルに記述したい」ぐらいの記述だと納得はできます。

それはそうと、具体的な問題に対する具体的なコードを求めているのか、アルゴリズム、つまり計算量的に良さそうな回答が欲しいのかを確定させないと議論(回答)が発散しそうだ、というのには賛成なので、クローズ投票しました。

Comment: Yuki Inoueさんへ。あなたは、何のために意見を書いているのですか？
『質問』には、『回答』が当たり前であって、気に入らなければスルーすればよいだけの話。わざわざ火種をばらまかないでいただきたいと思います。
質問者は、解らないから聞くのであって、回答者のご機嫌にそって質問するわけではないので、ある一部のサイトのように、上級者は『プログラマとはいかなるものか』を論じる場にされては困ります。初心者だから聞くわけなのですから、その相手に質問が気に入らないというのも、エゴ的だと思います。
それとも、いちいち『気に入らない』と書き込まなければ、気が済まないのでしょうか。

Comment: @たたぱた ひょっとして、質問につけられた「オフトピックである理由:...」というコメントについての話でしたら、あれはクローズ投票する際に自動で投稿されるコメントで、クローズすべきと考える理由を質問者や他のユーザーに説明するためのものです。

Comment: 気に入らないから文句を言っているわけではないと思いますよ？コメントは基本的に不足情報を要求する場所です。現在の質問では推測できない情報に対して要求しているのであって「ここが気に食わないからやめろ」といっているわけではないと思います。条件が不明なのでアルゴリズムを考えるのに支障が出ていると言えばいいでしょうか？ちょっと攻撃的になりすぎかと思います。

Comment: @たたぱた それと、ここでいう質問のクローズ（改善待ちとも言います）は一時的なものを想定しています。あなたがコメントに書かれたような、具体的な条件の提示を待ってから回答を集めたほうが、より質問者の方が求める回答が得られ、コミュニティでの評価もできるだろうという趣旨です。

Comment: @たたぱた エゴではありません。いかにこのサイトを良くするかという目標に向かって行動した結果であり、また積極的にそういった行動をすることがこのサイトでは推奨されています。現にそれをきっかけとしてこのトピックのような建設的な議論がなされています。回答することは「当たり前」ではないし、問題だと思えば「スルー」ではなく問題提起すべきです。