# 分析: 「いいライブラリ / ツールはありませんか」系のQ&Aでもっと欲張るには

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 回答の仕方

### お題

「[C#でHTMLを操作したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1745/30)」について、この質問は

- おすすめを求める主観的な質問である → だとすると問題ない
- 定番を求める一覧系質問である → だとするとよくない

という見方に分かれるのでは、という意見が出ています。それに対して私の解釈を述べます。

<sub>この投稿のきっかけになったのがこの質問、というだけで、この質問が特によい・わるいというわけではありません。ですので「お題」とは言いながら、そのQ&A内容に深入りはしません。質問内でコメントを下さった方の本意とも、質問された方の意図ともずれているかもしれませんが、よい題材なので仮にこの2つを論点として進めます。</sub>

### 「鍵をください」という比喩で考える

「ライブラリを教えてください」という質問は、「この鍵穴に合う鍵をください」というリクエストのようなものです。

[image: あなたが落とした鍵は]

ちょうど合う鍵を差し出すには、鍵穴の形状を教えてもらう必要があります。形状が分かれば、鍵穴に合うか合わないかはある程度客観的に判断できます。

あてはまる鍵が複数あった場合、どれがいいかを判断するのは最終的には主観的な判断です。その判断基準は、質問者が提示することもあれば、回答者が説明の一部として提供することもあります。

回答側はその判断基準をいかに満たしているかを示し、質問者側がそれを評価しベストアンサーを選べば、リクエストの処理は終了です。

<sub>質問者が指定する条件は、判断基準も含めてすべて「鍵の形状」とも言えますが、便宜上、分けて考えます。</sub>

### お題にあてはめて考える

お題の質問では、**鍵穴の形状**に関しては、「jQueryのようにDOM操作ができる」という条件があるので、回答を出すための最低限の条件は指定されていると思います。「トラバーサル・要素の追加削除・属性設定」などの機能が具体的に列挙されていてもいいかもしれません。

**「定番を求める一覧系質問」という解釈:**  
この場合、「（定番であればあるほどよい、という）判断基準があらかじめ提示されている質問」ということになります。

[image: 条件付き質問]

「定番かどうか」はある程度客観的に決められること、回答の数も限定されてくることから、落とし穴にははまりにくい[一覧系質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1382/30)といえます。回答側としては、「定番である」という証拠や経験談を提示できればベターであると思います。パッケージのインストール数やGitHubのLike数、周囲での使用状況など。

<sub>お題の質問では、回答へのコメントの流れで私が「定番」という言葉を出しただけなので、質問自体は明示的に定番を求めてはいません。</sub>

**「おすすめを求める主観的な質問」という解釈:**  
この場合、判断基準を回答者に丸投げした、「主観的な回答を求める質問」ということになります。「鍵穴」の条件が具体的なので、手に負えない程ではない[「主観的リスト質問」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1382/30)と言えると思います。

こうした質問では[「建設的な主観的質問のガイドライン」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1485/30)（長文注意）が参考になると考えています。

[image: おすすめをとりあえず]

本当に参考になる「主観的」な回答を書くには、鍵を差し出すだけでなく、判断基準をこちらから提示し、提案した鍵がその基準をどう満たしているかを説明する努力が必要になります。

それをしない場合、例えば家電量販店で「4kテレビのおすすめを見せてください」というお客様に「こちらにございます」と言って終わるようなものです。そこでさらに「どこがどういいのか」を解説した方が親切であると思います。

[image: こちらにございます]

質問側としても、判断基準をあらかじめ指定しておくと、知りたいことを解説してくれる回答を引き出すことができます。

とはいえ、何を基準によしあしを考えたらいいのかも分からない状態で質問する場合もあります。そういう時は、お互いに条件や情報を引き出しながら解決をめざすことになるでしょう。

### まとめ

「こういうのはありませんか」「はいコレ」で満足することなく、

- 質問: 求めるものの条件と判断基準をなるべく具体的に書く
- 回答: ライブラリ/ツールを回答するだけでなく、それがなぜ、どのように条件にマッチするのか、できれば経験を踏まえて具体的に書く

を目指すことで、お互いにより参考になる質問・回答をし、より魅力的なコンテンツを蓄積することができると考えます。

他にも注意するとよいと思うことはありますか？逆にここは反対、という箇所など、ご意見ください。