# タイポの質問にクローズ票を投じることができるようにして欲しい。

Tags: 機能の要求

質問の中に時々単なるタイポ（打ち間違い・記憶違いによる名前が違ってプログラムが動作しない）で投稿されるものがあります。

本家の場合タイポのよるクローズ投票ができるようになっていますが、
日本語版の場合その項目がありません。
もちろん、「タイポが原因なのでクローズ投票をします」（そしてタイポがなぜオフトピックになるか）というような理由を自分で書けば良いわけではあるのですが、
結構頻発する事柄のように思いますので、
タイポの質問に項目の一つとしてクローズ票を投じることができるようにして欲しいと思います。

（逆にできないというか本家から変更した理由はなんでしょうか？）

Comment: 本家のそれはシステム上は[「サイトごとに設定できるオフトピック理由」](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448221?opt.textResults=true)という扱いなのですが、日本語版はデフォルトのオフトピック理由をそのまま使っている、という経緯ですね。他にも必要なものがあれば3つまで追加できます。

Comment: @unarist  なるほど、日本語版にあたって変更されたという訳ではないのですね。

Answer (score 0):

コメントでunaristが伝えたとおり、各サイトは３つのカスタムクローズ理由はあります。

英語版では３つあります：

1. おすすめな本・ツール・ライブラリ等の質問
2. コードそのままペーストしたデバグに関する質問（このコードはなぜうまく行かないか？）
3. 質問の原因はタイポの質問（`whlie i = true` -> `while i = true`)

英語版では日本語版より質問が多いし、歴史もあるので、コミュニティで上記の理由を決めました。当サイトではおすすめな質問を禁止されているより、[一部の質問を受け入れようとの話がありました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1512/%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90-%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA-%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B-%E7%B3%BB%E3%81%AEqa%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E6%AC%B2%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)。

もちろん、皆様がそれを討議できますが、「英語版にあるから・・・」と言う理由より、「当コミュニティでは○○が必要」との討議の方がいいと思います。

（英語版でも多くのユーザーが「おすすめ質問を禁止されるより、おすすめ質問のいい書き方に努力すればよかった」と言っている人もいます）

Comment: 「英語版にあるから・・・」という理由で欲しい機能というよりタイポの質問は当人にとってはわからないものではあっても、Q&Aサイトとしては価値のないQ&Aでありオフトピックであることがはっきりしていると思うからです。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 現在はカスタムなクローズ理由で手動に「タイポです」とかでクローズができます。頻度が少なかったら、手動でもいいと思いますし、手動でどの理由をつけているかを見たうえでデフォルトを増やすこともできます。現在どの頻度でこの理由を使っていますか？

Comment: はい、カスタムクローズで対応可能ということは質問に含ませて置きました。現状全体的な頻度としては多くはないと思いますが、個人的には、２日で二回（同一人物）タイポの質問に遭遇しました。その内日本語版が活発になるにつれ頻度も増えると考えますが、当面この質問がupvoteされないし討議もないような状態であれば管理者としてはとりあえず様子見というのは理解できます。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY なるほど！討議が目的なら、メタで是非投稿してください！