# タイポが原因であった質問はクローズするべきでしょうか

Tags: 討議, 質問のクローズ

タイポ（ミスタイプ）の指摘で解決した質問はクローズするべきでしょうか。

関連: [タイポの質問にクローズ票を投じることができるようにして欲しい。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2131/3054)

---

補足:

- クローズを検討する理由になるタイポは、
  質問に含まれるタイポ全般ではなく、質問者のコード中に存在し、それが質問内容の**原因の全て**になっているものを指します。
- タイポの指摘は、
  回答やコメントで「ここでタイポしているのがエラーの原因です。正しい記述はこうですよ」
  と、**質問者に理解出来る形**でなされている事が前提です。
- 解決したか否かの判断は、
  例えば以下のような点によります。

  - 質問者によりタイポを指摘する回答が**承認された**場合
  - 質問者からコメントなどで「これで解決しました」という**報告があった**場合
  - 放置されているが、タイポが原因だった事が**傍目からもほぼ確実**である場合

具体例:
[`length` を `lenght` としたタイポ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31571/3054)
[`tmpText` を 別の変数 `text` と間違えたもので、タイポかそれに近いミス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/19144/3054)

Answer (score 5):

タイポは単純なミスではありますが、ミスをするにはそれなりの理由があり、一概にクローズすべきではないと考えます。

具体例に挙げられている[lengthをlenghtとしたタイポ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/31576/4236)、またタイポではありませんが[閉じ括弧漏れ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/32103/4236)、どちらも単にミスを指摘するのは簡単ですが、それだけにとどまらずミスを防ぐ手立てを回答することも可能だと思います。
質問自体は恥ずかしいかもしれませんが、多くの人に役立つQ&Aが書けると考えますのでクローズすべきではないと考えます。可能であれば [lengthをlenghtとしたタイポ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31571/4236) もリオープンを希望します。

Comment: 「一概に」という部分の理解に自信がないので確認させていただきたいのですが、基本的にタイポを理由にはクローズするべきではない、というご意見という事でよろしいでしょうか。それとも、基本はクローズだけれども、ミスを防ぐ手立てなどを含めた良い Q&A になった物、あるいはなりそうな物に関してのみは、クローズすべきでない、というご意見でしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

私は以下の様なケースを除き、クローズでよいと思います。

- ありがちなタイポで、今後も質問者以外から参照され得るもの
- 単純なタイポではなく、文法への無理解などが原因にあるもの
- 回答を通じて、タイポの発見方法などが共有されたもの

---

ただ、クローズする場合は理由の説明を丁寧にしないと、サイト初心者のユーザーが混乱しますので、そこが課題になると思います（クローズ一般に言える事かも知れませんが）。

Comment: タイポ箇所の指摘がないクローズは混乱すると思いますので(自分では気づかないものですし…)タイポ箇所の指摘もあわせて出来るといいですね。箇条書きにされている件に関しても同意しますが、無理にクローズする必要は無い気もします。(同じようなタイポ質問がいくつもあっては困りますが、レビュワーの胸三寸でしょうか？)、タイポ質問は大半が原因追求の出来ない初心者のミスだと思いますので、自分としては出来る限りフォローしてあげたいのが本音です。

Comment: @Myaku そうですね。おっしゃる点は前提としてなされるべきですね。質問の方に補足しておきました。