# ヘルプセンターの on-topic に以下の文章を追加したい

Tags: 討議, ヘルプ, 話題の範囲

ヘルプセンターの[「ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)は、本家 Stack Overflow における ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) にあたります。後者のヘルプには、日本語訳版で訳されている範囲に続き、以下の記述があります。

> **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**
>
> 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
> 2. Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.
> 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.
> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

<sup>(補足: 日本語版スタック・オーバーフローに関連するであろう部分だけ抜粋しました。)</sup>

この部分を以下のように日本語訳してみました。これを、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローの当該ヘルプにも追記したいと考えたのですが、いかがでしょうか。

> **上のリストにある話題に沿っていても、オフトピックな質問とされることがあります。**
>
> 1. デバッグを求める質問 (「どうしてこのコードは動かないのですか？」) は、してほしい動作、解決したい問題やエラー、そして問題を再現するための最小限のソースコードを質問の中に書かなければいけません。[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)もご覧ください。
> 2. 第三者が再現できない問題や、簡単な打ち間違いが原因のエラーに関する質問は好ましくありません。このような質問をしてしまわないためにも、質問中に[問題を再現する必要最小限のプログラム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)が含まれているか、投稿前に確認してください。
> 3. 宿題に関する質問では、その課題を解決するためにあなたが今までどのようなことを試したのかを要約し、そして、課題に取り組む中でどのような壁にぶつかったのかを説明してください。
> 4. オススメの書籍やツール、ライブラリ、チュートリアルなどを教えて欲しい・探して欲しいといった質問は、スタック・オーバーフローではオフトピックです。このような質問には主観的な回答やスパム投稿がよく付きます。このような質問をする代わりに、今あなたが直面している問題を説明し、それを解決するために今まで何をしてきたのかを説明してください。

Comment: これらをヘルプに追加するイコール、本質的にはオフトピック範囲の変更もしくは詳細化になります。それにあたっては、4項目について個別に「これはオフトピックとするか」という議論をおこなった方がよいのではないかと思ったのですが、どうでしょうか。https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2131/30 は「タイポをクローズ理由として追加しては」という方向でしたが、一歩手前の「オフトピックとするか」という方向で新たにスレを立てる価値はあるように思います。（あるいは、この文章を追加したいと思われた動機を私が把握できてないのかもしれません。）

Comment: @ento コメントありがとうございます。タイポの投稿は見逃していました、参考になります。確かに個別でオフトピック案件としてメタ投稿を作るのが良いかもしれません。私としましても、この投稿に対しプラス投票もマイナス投票もなかなか入らないため、どうしたものかと思っておりました。時間がとれたときに投稿してみようかと思います（あるいはどなたかお願いいたします）。

Comment: メモ: いくつか考えてみて、この文面をそのまま使うのではなく、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローの現状に合わせて変えた方が良さそうな気がしてきました。まとまったらメタに投稿したいと思います。

Comment: メモ: 宿題についての既存質問では、未だに on-topic / off-topic が紛糾しているように見えます。個人的には、on / off の境界線は宿題を理由としているのではなく、宿題質問によくある特徴が理由となっているのではないかと思えてきました。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/19110