# ヘルプセンターの on-topic ページにおける情報量が、英語版より日本語版では少ないのはなぜ？

Tags: 討議, ヘルプ, 話題の範囲

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
の日本語版にあたるのは
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
だと思うのですが、英語版にくらべて情報量が少ないです。

英語版にある下記内容、特に「再現性」や「宿題」そして「単におすすめを聞く」等について、質問者さんにそれらはうまく質問しないとオフトピックですよと伝えたいのですが、日本語のヘルプだとできなさそうな気がするのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？

> Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the
> categories listed above:
>
> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
> include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
> shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See:
> How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
>
> Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was
> caused by a simple typographical error. This can often be avoided by
> identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to
> reproduce the problem before posting.
>
> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work
> you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
> difficulty you are having solving it.
>
> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
> library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
> Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
> Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
> it.
>
> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
> for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
> for programming.
>
> Questions on professional server, networking, or related
> infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
> they directly involve programming or programming tools.
>
> Questions asking for support for offsite resources such as App Stores
> are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Direct your questions to the
> relevant organisation instead.
>
> Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are
> off-topic for Stack Overflow. Open Source Stack Exchange or Law Stack
> Exchange may be suitable alternatives.

Comment: 関連: [ヘルプセンターの「ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?」の内容はこれでよいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1389/32986)

Comment: 重複候補: [ヘルプセンターの on-topic に以下の文章を追加したい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2541)

Answer (score 4):

スタック・オーバーフローが Stack Overflow とは異なる範囲の話題を扱うことに起因して、メタ上での[議論が行われた結果](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292/32986)、ヘルプセンターの文言に[変更が加えられました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1389/32986)。このような経緯から、現状では「再現性がない」、「宿題」や「単におすすめを聞く」といった質問がオフトピックになる可能性について、**ヘルプセンターで直接的には言及されていません**。

その代わりに、こういった質問が幾つかのクローズ理由に該当する可能性を示すことが出来ます。

---

#### 再現性のない質問

[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)の「ソフトウェア開発に固有の、実際的で**回答可能な**問題である」という部分でオフトピックに該当するかもしれません。

また、再現性のないソースコードでは問題の共有と解決が行えない場合があります。このようなときには質問へ情報の追加や修正が必要になるため、「より詳細に、または明確にする必要がある」というクローズ理由に該当し**クローズされる可能性があります**。さらに、[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)には以下のような記述があります。

> 質問をする際、第三者が質問の内容を理解し、手元で問題を再現できるような良いサンプルコードを含めると、より良い回答をもらいやすくなります。

---

#### 宿題に関する質問

宿題に関する質問自体はスタック・オーバーフローでは**オントピック**です。ただし、他の一般的な質問と同様に、クローズ理由のいずれかが該当する可能性もあります。これは、ヘルプセンターの以下の記事を読むことで未然に防げると思います。

- [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [質問が [クローズ済み] とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)
- [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

もしかすると、宿題に関する質問が法的または道義的問題を孕んでいるかもしれませんが、これはオフトピックであるかの判断に影響しません。

---

#### 単におすすめを尋ねる質問

このような質問がオントピックかどうかは、ヘルプセンターから判断出来ませんが、少なくともヘルプセンターの[どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)に書かれている「主観的な質問」に該当し、**クローズされる可能性があります**。

> 質問が通報されるのを予防するため (削除の可能性も)、次のような主観的な質問は避けてください。
>
> - どの回答も同様に有効:「好きな ______ は何ですか?」
> - 質問と一緒に回答も提示され、さらに他の回答を期待している:「私は ______ に ______ を使用しています。皆さんは何を使用しますか?」
> - 解決すべき実際の問題がない:「他の人が私と同じように感じるか興味があります。」
> - 質問を装った暴言: 「______ は最悪ですよね?」

ただし、このような質問であっても**内容が建設的であればクローズされることはありません**。建設的であるかどうかの基準は、[いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1485/32986)や[どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)から知ることが出来ます。

> 一部の主観的な質問は許されますが、「主観的」とは「何でもあり」という意味ではありません。すべての主観的な質問は建設的であることが期待されます。どういう意味でしょうか?建設的で主観的な質問とは以下のようなものです。
>
> - 「なぜ」と「どうやって」を説明する回答を引き出す
> - 短い回答ではなく長い回答がつきやすい
> - 建設的で公正、かつ偏らないトーンである
> - 意見よりも経験を共有することを歓迎する
> - 意見が事実と参考資料で裏付けされていると主張する
> - 単なる思慮のない交流を楽しむものではない