# プログラミングにおいてオススメの資料・本など

Tags: サポート

私は現在独学でコンパイラ・OS・CPU・アセンブラといった低レイヤーに入門したいと考えています。そこで、そういったものを初学者が勉強し始める上で、オススメの本や資料といったものをこちらstackoverflow metaを通して他のユーザーに聞くというのは可能でしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こちらの「メタ」では「スタック・オーバーフロー」そのものについての**使い方**に関する質問をやり取りする場なので、プログラム関連など通常の疑問を投げる場とは少し違います。
また、メインのスタック・オーバーフローにおいても「オススメの○○を教えてください」といった質問は避けられる傾向にあります。詳しくは以下のやり取りを参考にしてみてください。

[「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/3060)